# UOWHF vs CRHF / Relevance of UOWHF

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, terminology, universal-hash

What's the difference between UOWHF and CRHF and why are UOWHF useful?

As far as I understand, Universal One-Way Hash Functions are an alternative to CRHF. While for CRHF it is hard, given randomly chosen hash function parameters, to find any collision of the hash function; for UOWHF it's hard to find a collision where one preimage is chosen independently of the hash function parameters.

How does this difference affect the behaviour of the functions and why are UOWHF so relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a combination of:

1. [UOWHF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_one-way_hash_function) is a weaker primitive than [CRHF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) (collision resistance implies universal one-wayness) and it turns out that it can be (black-box) constructed from [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) (OWFs) [NY,R]. While, CRHFs cannot be (black-box) constructed from OWFs [S].
2. For some applications, (e.g., [digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) [NY]) UOWHFs suffice instead of collision resistance.

[NY]: Naor and Yung, [*Universal One-Way Hash Functions and their Cryptographic Applications*](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Enaor/PAPERS/uowhf_abs.html), STOC'89

[R]: Rompel, [*One-way functions are necessary and sufficent for secure signatures*](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs276/fa20/notes/Rompel.pdf),STOC'90

[S]: Simon. [*Finding collisions on a one-way street: Can secure hash functions be based on general assumptions?*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0054137.pdf), Eurocrypt'98.